# How to add Aggregate (Sum) To Kendo UI Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, bar-chart

I have a simple bar chart with basic data.  The tooltip shows the specific **value** it is representing which is good.  I want to, just below it, show the Total for that entire bar/stack.  So if the top bar had 10, 20, 50 for its corresponding values, the total for that stack/bar would be 80.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z2djd51f/1/) that shows the working bar chart.

Is it possible to have the tooltip show the value and total?

I have tried using aggregate at the seriesDefault level, within the series and a few others to no avail.  I typically try the following for my tooltip format:

```
"#= series.name # #= kendo.format('{0:C0}', value) #<br />#= kendo.format('{0:C0}', sum) #";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a regular template:

```
<script id="altTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
 #: series.name # -  #: value #
 # var chartOptions = $("\#chartBreakout").data("kendoChart").options #   
 # var categories = chartOptions.categoryAxis.categories #
 # var allSeries = chartOptions.series #
 # var catIndex = categories.indexOf(category) #   
 # var total = 0 # 
 # for (var i = 0; i < allSeries.length; i++) { # 
 #    total += allSeries[i].data[catIndex] #
 # } #
 Total - #: total #
</script>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zkvt25xy/1/)

You could change it to a shared Template

```
tooltip: {
    visible: true,
    shared: true,
    sharedTemplate: kendo.template($("#template").html())
}
```

Then your template would be something like:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
<div>#: category #</div>
# var total = 0; #
# for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) { #
<div>#: points[i].series.name# : #: points[i].value #</div>
# total += points[i].value #
# } #
Total #: total #
</script>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hbdbr486/)

Comment: I like it.  Without diving into the code, is it possible to still have it broken out and each one has its own value and the total?  Or am I stuck with the shared version?  Thank you very much though.

Comment: @Grandizer See my changes for a regular template that will work.

Comment: I do not want to sound unappreciative, but the second fiddle is exactly like the first.  I am guessing perhaps you didn't save the fiddle?  And of course, now I am excited to see the update.  ;)

Comment: @Grandizer oops.. try it now. :)